# StreamBuilder is not reading data from Stream as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use a StreamBuilder to read some data from a Stream, but snapshot.data is only returning the last item from the Stream. In this case, I am only getting 'f'. I want to get 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'. What am I doing wrong?

```
class ProgressWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  //ProgressWidget({this.stream}) : super();
  //final Stream<String> stream;

  @override
  _ProgressWidgetState createState() => _ProgressWidgetState();
}

class _ProgressWidgetState extends State<ProgressWidget> {
  int _progressCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Stream.fromIterable(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']),  // test stream
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          _progressCount++;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data);
          }
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? new Text('Progress $_progressCount ' + snapshot.data)
              : new Text('Loading ... ');
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the same as in your previous question: under the hood `StreamBuilder` is a `StatefulWidget` which is calling multiple `setState()` in the same frame (or maybe tries to be smarter and simply skips calling when not needed): you cannot avoid it but now your code is much more simple than using `await _stream.forEach((line)` and things like that

Comment: why do you insist to rebuild your widget on every item in the stream? remeber that `setState` is synchronized with 60Hz so... it would be damn slow to show everything...

Comment: Sorry, I am new to flutter, still learning

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html, the first paragraph says: *"Widget rebuilding is scheduled by each interaction, using State.setState, but is otherwise decoupled from the timing of the stream. The builder is called at the discretion of the Flutter pipeline, and will thus receive a timing-dependent sub-sequence of the snapshots that represent the interaction with the stream."*

Comment: but even if your `StreamBuilder` does not show all of your data, it does not mean that some data is not read from your stream - it simply is not shown

Comment: My problem is I am trying to read a large file, and I need to show progress to the user every couple lines read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class _ProgressWidgetState extends State<ProgressWidget> {
  int _progressCount = 0;
  Stream<String> _stream;
  List<String> _source = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => _source[i]).take(_source.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _stream, // test stream
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        _progressCount++;
        return snapshot.hasData ? new Text('Progress $_progressCount ' + snapshot.data) : new Text('Loading ... ');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks, but I gotta figure out how to read a large file and display progress every certain number of lines loaded.

Comment: You may want to check Dio client, I've seen that it has a progress callback, I suppose that it can be used to monitor how many bytes have been downloaded

Answer (score 1):

Create your stream like this:

```
Stream<String> listStream(Duration interval, List<String> list) async* {
      int i = 0;
      while (i<list.length) {
        await Future.delayed(interval);
        yield list[i];
        i++;
      }
    }
```

Final code:

```
class ProgressWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  //ProgressWidget({this.stream}) : super();
  //final Stream<String> stream;

  @override
  _ProgressWidgetState createState() => _ProgressWidgetState();
}

class _ProgressWidgetState extends State<ProgressWidget> {
  int _progressCount = 0;
  String str = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
Stream<String> listStream(Duration interval, List<String> list) async* {
  int i = 0;
  while (i<list.length) {
    await Future.delayed(interval);
    yield list[i];
    i++;
  }
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream:listStream(Duration(milliseconds:300), ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          _progressCount++;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            str += snapshot.data;
          }
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? new Text('Progress $_progressCount ' + str)
              : new Text('Loading ... ');
        });
  }
}
```